# How to pass file name at run time in python

Tags: python

I have a directory which contains 4 .csv files at the moment.
I am able retrieve their names using os lib in the code given below:

```
import os
fileNames = os.listdir(path)

for f in fileNames:
        print(f)
```

Now I want to pass the file names one by one in my open file command and do the related processing.

how do I pass file name in my command:

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\hu170f\Documents\TEST1\<filename to be passed>')
```

Comment: You can pass the name as a variable and then attach it to the string there

Comment: Have you tried `file = open(r'C:\Users\hu170f\Documents\TEST1\'+f)`?

Comment: @Kristian yes I did that but it's not working

Comment: @MananAdhvaryu how do I do it. Can you help.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
dir_path = r'D:\text_dirs\\'
fileNames = os.listdir(dir_path)

for fn in fileNames:
    f = open(dir_path+fn, "r")
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: If I just have to print the file path along with file the name it is working fine. May be I haven't put up my question correctly. under the for loop I want to open the file one by one using command : file = open(r'<entire filepath>').

Comment: @shikha check now . I have opened a dir of txt files and am able to  print.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = r"C:\..."
filenames = os.listdir(path)
```

You can use the `map` function like a `for` loop, which only opens one method(The first parameter) and passes one after one element of this list(second parameter) to the method. The `lambda` function is like a method which executes the `open` function and returns the `_io.TextIOWrapper`. `files` contains a list of `_io.TextIOWrapper`.

```
files = list(map(lambda filename: open(f"{path}\{filename}"), filenames))
```